# How do I escape a brace in an interpolated string, after a brace with a format string?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

The following crashes:

```
$"{{{DayOfWeek.Friday:d}}}"
```

If I put a space after the first closing brace, it works, but I don't want a space there.

So 2 questions:

1. Why does it crash, instead of treating the last 2 braces as a literal brace?
2. How can I do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [Escaping Braces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#escaping-braces) documentation

> For example, consider the format item "{{{0:D}}}", which is intended
>   to display an opening brace, a numeric value formatted as a decimal
>   number, and a closing brace. However, the format item is actually
>   interpreted in the following manner: The first two opening braces
>   ("{{") are escaped and yield one opening brace. The next three
>   characters ("{0:") are interpreted as the start of a format item. The
>   next character ("D") would be interpreted as the Decimal standard
>   numeric format specifier, but the next two escaped braces ("}}") yield
>   a single brace. Because the resulting string ("D}") is not a standard
>   numeric format specifier, the resulting string is interpreted as a
>   custom format string that means display the literal string "D}".

This is exactly your case, you are getting incorrect format specifier as a result.

For you code you can try to use the old `string.Format`

```cs
string.Format("{0}{1:d}{2}", "{", DayOfWeek.Friday, "}");
```